# Catching PHP errors if XML file is empty

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

so I'm grabbing some information from an XML file like so:

```
$url = "http://myurl.blah";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Except sometimes the XML file is empty and I need the code to fail gracefully but I can't seem to figure out how to catch the PHP error. I tried this:

```
if(isset(simplexml_load_file($url)));
{
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    /*rest of code using $xml*/
}
else {
    echo "No info avilable.";
}
```

But it doesn't work. I guess you can't use ISSET that way. Anyone know how to catch the error?

Comment: In general, you can use the `try {} catch (exception $e) {}` pair.

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` does not throw exceptions. It raises `E_WARNING` errors.

Comment: @mellamokb The PHP error informing me that the file is empty. What else?

Comment: To be exact: Warning: simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: http://myurl.blah:1: parser error : Document is empty in blah...

Comment: @AzzyDude: Sorry, I didn't realize `simplexml_load_file` was built-in... you may find the tip helpful on the [documentation page](php.net/simplexml_load_file): `Use libxml_use_internal_errors() to suppress all XML errors, and libxml_get_errors() to iterate over them afterwards.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$xml = file_get_contents("http://myurl.blah");
if (trim($xml) == '') {
    die('No content');
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Or, possibly slightly more efficient, but not necessarily recommended because it silences errors:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($url);
if (!$xml) {
    die('error');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `isset` here.

```
// Shutdown errors (I know it's bad)
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($url);

// Check you have fetch a response
if (false !== $xml); {
    //rest of code using $xml
} else {
    echo "No info avilable.";
}
```

Comment: Don't use `empty` here, `if ($xml)` will do just fine.

Comment: Hmm, `false !==` is pretty ugly as well IMO, but better than `empty`.

Comment: @deceze Why do you think it's ugly?

Comment: _Yoda conditions_ are part of a lot framework coding standards (ZF, Symfony, Doctrine, etc). It really prevents being fooled by `if ($xml = /* something */) {`

Comment: I trust that `if ($xml)` will always be `true` if `$xml` is a `SimpleXML` object and `false` otherwise...

Comment: I agree with this but I prefer test real return value (`false` here) rather than type casted one. Each developer has his own CS.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (($xml = simplexml_load_file($url)) !== false) {
  // Everything is OK. Use $xml object.
} else {
  // Something has gone wrong!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP manual, error handling ([click here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)):

```
var_dump(libxml_use_internal_errors(true));

// load the document
$doc = new DOMDocument;

if (!$doc->load('file.xml')) {
    foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        // handle errors here
    }

    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```