# check if xml exists (simplexml_load_file)

Tags: php

I'm reading an XML file for a number. It then uses that number for a URL parameter which can be used as an XML as well. There are a few cases where the XML doesn't exist. When that happens I would like for the page to report that there are no stats for that game.

TL;DR: If the XML doesn't exist, how can I get it to simply echo "No Stats."

```
$gamepage = simplexml_load_file('' . rawurlencode($gamelink) . '?xml=1');
```

Comment: Is the XML a local file or are you pulling it over http? If local, just [`file_exists()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722613/check-if-a-remote-page-exists-using-php and [many other examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+remote+file+exists).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$a = simplexml_load_string($somestring);
if($a===FALSE) {
   echo 'No Stats';
} else {
   echo "Valid XML found... processing."; 
}
```

Simple as pie.

Comment: If the xml returned is blank, this will still throw an error. This is a much better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11633904/1312282