# PHP -> How can I check if a XML is empty

Tags: php, xml

I get simple xml content from a request after a certain ID. But sometimes an ID isn't anymore available and the XML is empty.

How can I check with PHP if a xml is empty?

If someone has an idea I would appreciate if he could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Marco

Comment: What do you mean by saying it's empty?
You can compare it to empty string like $xml == "" ?
Or use the xml class to check if it has "children".

Comment: If it's a file you could just check the filesize

Comment: @Chevi As I understood it, a XML file could have contents, but the XML document is still empty; for example when only having a `<?xml version="1.0"?>` or an empty root-element. Thus the question from Ofir Baruch: how does the OP define "empty" in case of an XML document?

Answer (score 13):

If you can use **SimpleXML** extention:

```
$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlText);
if ($xmlObject->count() == 0) {
    //it's empty
}
else {
    //XML object has children
}
```

Also, SimpleXML is a very handy XML-reader/editor.

Details: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: If you want to know if a child node is empty this solution is not fit. For example `<a>123</a>` and `<b/>` both has count 0.

Answer (score 8):

I guess it depends on what you mean by empty, if the entire document is empty, you can check if the string version of the document is empty with:

```
if (empty($xmlString)) 
{
    // is empty 
}
```

But if you're expecting a root node, you might need to check if there are any children:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

if (empty($xml->getName()) && count($xml->children()) == 0) { 
    // is empty
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the xml returned is blank, this will still throw an error. This is a much better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11633904/1312282

Answer (score 2):

just use (string) before your id and it will work.
example:-
your code is like this
$id            = $xml->mail->id;

then make it just like this
$id            = (string)$xml->mail->id;

it will work

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my two cents to an old question, but the top rated answer seems to suggest using 
simplexml_load_file("test.xml"); and then testing that a node you expect is not empty. As this would thrown a warning level error if the file is empty, I would disagree and instead wrap the call with a test for filesize.

```
$xmlInfo = new SplFileInfo('test.xml');
if((int) $xmlInfo->getSize() > 0)
{
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlInfo->getPath());  
}
```

Of course OP has asked `How can I check with PHP if a xml is empty`, which doesn't specify if he means node or file, but for completeness there it is.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$xml_str = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><Name/>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_str);

if(empty($xml->Name[0])){
    // ITS EMPTY !! DO SOMETHING
    echo "ITS EMPTY ASJK";
}
```